# What happens to symbolic link？The original binary file and symbolic binary file act different

Tags: linux, symlink

When I have installed [Basic TeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html), I find that `pdflatex` is simply a symbolic link to `pdftex` which is under the same directory. However, When I try to compile my tex file directly by `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex`, the compiling process becomes interactive that I need to hit `return` button continually until compiling finished. But if I use `pdflatex`, the output seems different. What happened to `pdftex` when it is symbolic linked? Can symbolic link change binary files executing behaviour?

### Update:

`pdftex`'s output is shown below:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  [letter]{article}
?
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \usepackage
               [margin=0.5in]{geometry}
?
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \begin
          {document}
?
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \section
            *{Problem 1}
?
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \subsection
               *{Algorithm}
?
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
)</usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.
pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 15945 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

And, `pdflatex` prints this:

```
his is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 21 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [letter].

(./test.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/a
msfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 21292 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: "the output seems different" -- how?

Comment: I have pasted the outputs of both `pdftex` and `pdflatex` in UPDATE section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They know their name. You can reproduce this by examining `argv[0]`.

Comment: To be pedantic, the calling process (usually the shell) tells them their name.

Comment: I think `pdflatex` and `pdftex` should be identical, since `pdflatex` is a symbolic link to `pdftex` and the OS will translate the symlink to the path of `pdftex`.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up @Pacholik, the program knows the name that was used when you ran the program.  The program knows if you activated it by running `pdftex` or if you activated it by running `pdflatex`.